# Blinking text on ProgressBar

Tags: c#, controls, progress-bar

I wrote a control. And when i execute program text on progressbar is blinking.

```
     public class ProgressBarPercentage : ProgressBar
        {
            private int percent;//user defined step

            public void SetProgressBarText(string text)
            {
                using (Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    this.Refresh();
                    gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + " %", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black,
                        new PointF(this.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + " %", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F),
                        this.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + " %", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)));
                }
            }

            public void SetPercent(int percent)
            {
                this.percent = percent;
                if (this.Value < 100)
                    this.Value = percent;
                else
                    this.Value = 99;

            }
        }

static void Main
{
            ProgressBarWindow.ProgressBarPercentage progress = new ProgressBarWindow.ProgressBarPercentage();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {     
        progress.SetPercent(i);
        progress.SetProgressBarText(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can you say me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your question needs more informations. Do you get any exception or error message? Only _Can you say me what I did wrong?_ is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: when I run this program the text is disappearing and appears again when I reappropriate this.Value.

Comment: Sorry, for my bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think, You will see the blink effect by this, even if it works.

This is simply too fast.

You must perhaps use a timer to reduce the speed, or, also possible, System.Thread.Sleep()

Comment: I used your advice but it doesn't work.For example, when i do System.Thread.Sleep(1000), I see text only at the first second , but since second seconds till 1000 I don't see it.

Comment: You should add a try catch to Your code.
Then, lease verify that You have no exceptions.
And debug the stuff.

Comment: I already know, what i did wrong. Еvery time when I called SetProgressBar Text i effaced graphics and I don't know how fix it.

Comment: Do You had an exception ?
Like running out of memory perhaps ?

Comment: I have no an exception. I override OnPaint but it doesn't help

Comment: The graphics object perhaps is better to keep ir global, and dispose it manuall, you know, i will write it, too.

Comment: If I take graphics object as global it still redraws graphics. The test  still blinks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long time ago, but maybe this answer would be helpful for someone with similar problem. You can set style in constructor for this custom control like this:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Most important is ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer flag which can prevent controls from blinking when Paint is called in too short intervals.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx